# Kotlin - Spring - How to pass an interface with generics as an argument to Mockito.any()

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, generics, junit, mockito

In Kotlin I'm using Mockito to perform unit tests in the `when` method I'm trying to test my repository which extends JpaRepository which also extends QueryByExempleExecutor and from this interface I want the method `findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable)` which receives as its first argument the Example interface that has a generics

In Kotlin the method should work like this
 `` `when`(repository.findAll(Mockito.any(Example<Book>::class.java), Mockito.any(PageRequest::class.java))).thenReturn(page) ``

however it doesn't work and the only message I have is this "*Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal*"

how can I use the when method passing an interface to Mockito.any() ???

Comment: `Mockito.any(Example.class)` (I'm not used to Kotlin, maybe `Example::class.java`?)

Comment: what you commented is partially correct the problem is that Example is not a class but an interface what you commented for the class works correctly but not the same does not happen with the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension on mockito like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> any() = Mockito.any(T::class.java)
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
`when`(
    repository.findAll(
        example = Mockito.any<Example<Book>>(),
        pageable = Mockito.any<PageRequest>(),
    )
).thenReturn(page)
```

Comment: I write this inline function in my class of test???

Comment: Add it to your unit test package, probably in a utils package. Then you can use it in all your tests